# How to change the order of Feature and Apps on my developer story?

Tags: support, feature-request, developer-story, cv-export

I can just edit my CV through the story view, that means everything is based on time.

But I still use this as my CV and I used to export it as .pdf.
Now my issue that I want to sort Feature and Apps I have done by the importance and scale not based on the time I have done them.

Is there a way to do that without adding false datetimes on each project?

Comment: May I recommend writing a custom CV - I am sure LinkedIn's PDF export capability is useful for some things, but being a professional real-world CV is not one of them.

Comment: @tar there are millions of options to write your CV and export it, but I am a big fan of keeping my developer story on SO, and it used to work perfect, I just have this one issue.

Comment: Hm maybe this should be a feature request?

Comment: @YvetteColomb yes, I was just wondering if it is a feature already there and I missed it, but you are right seams that I need to add feature request tag.

Comment: yeh, I find it annoying also - it would be good to be able to customise what we show. I use the SO Dev story as my CV - it's a much easier way of staying on top of it.

Comment: or may be allow us to do the edits from the traditional view